# Who is the Name's Day Saint of St. John de Brébeuf?

Tags: catholicism, saint

Can anyone tell me who is the [name's day saint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_day) of [St. John de Brébeuf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_de_Br%C3%A9beuf)? The name's day saint of someone is similar to a [patron saint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patron_saint), but is not exactly the same. I have try to find a source that makes note of this but have come up empty handed so far.

St. Jean de Brébeuf was born on March 25, 1593 and was martyred on March 16, 1649 by the Iroquois Indians.

> A name day is a tradition in some countries in Europe, Latin America, and Catholic and Eastern Orthodox countries in general. It consists of celebrating a day of the year that is associated with one's given name. The celebration is similar to a birthday.
>
> The custom originated with the Christian calendar of saints: believers named after a saint would celebrate that saint's feast day, or in the Eastern Orthodox tradition, the day of a saint's death. Name days have greater resonance in the Catholic and Orthodox parts of Europe; Protestant churches practice less veneration of saints. In many countries, however, name-day celebrations no longer have connection to explicitly Christian traditions.
>
> The celebration of name days has been a tradition in Catholic and Eastern Orthodox countries since the Middle Ages, and has also continued in some measure in countries, such as the Scandinavian countries, whose Protestant established church retains certain Catholic traditions. The name days originate in the list of holidays celebrated in commemoration of saints and martyrs of the church. For example, the name Karl or Carl is celebrated in Sweden on January 28, the anniversary of the death of Charlemagne (Charles magnus, i.e., "the great"). The church promoted celebration of name days (or rather saints' feast days) over birthdays. - [Name day (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_day)

Comment: Do you mean, what saint did he adopt for his name saint (eg John the Evangelist versus John the Baptist?

Comment: Are you  wondering when St John de Brebeuf celebrated his name day (e.g. he may have celebrated it on June 24, or perhaps Dec 27 etc)  or are you asking about when a modern boy, called after him, should celebrate his name day?  Or something else?

Comment: @MattGutting Yes, that is what I desire to know.

Comment: @davidlol See Matt Gutting's comment.